# Using ogr2ogr how to set WKT format of .prj file?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I create a shapefile using this **ogr2ogr** command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -overwrite -a_srs EPSG:28992 -explodecollections \
-makevalid "Clipped.shp" "org.shp" -clipsrc "border.shp"
```

Because of `-a_srs` a .prj file is also created. When I look at https://epsg.io/28992 I can see the content of this .prj file is in `ESRI WKT`.
When I open this file in Surfer I get a warning the projection cannot be read.
When I replace the content of the .prj-file with the `OGC WKT` version, Surfer has no problems opening this file.
I assume ogr2ogr uses the `ESRI WKT` format because I set the format to `ESRI Shapefile`.

I tried adding `--config OSR_WKT_FORMAT` for all options (SFSQL WKT1_SIMPLE WKT1 WKT1_GDAL WKT1_ESRI WKT2_2015 WKT2_2018 WKT2 DEFAULT) but the .prj-file is always the same.

How do I instruct ogr2ogr to create the .prj file in `OGC WKT` format?

Comment: don't save to a shapefile if you don't want an ESRI prj file

Comment: Thanks Ian for your response, but creating a shapefile is mandatory. `--config OSR_WKT_FORMAT` suggests you can change it. But how?

Comment: I think it's specified in the Shapefile spec so you can't over ride it for that format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a valid shapefile should use ESRI style .prj file because after all it is an ESRI format. But you obviously need a workaround so I suggest converting .prj by using the gdalsrsinfo utility https://gdal.org/programs/gdalsrsinfo.html.

Example:

Use the ESRI style input

```
test.prj
========
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

gdalsrsinfo -o WKT2 test.prj

GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ID["EPSG",6326]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]]
```

Comment: I tried it and it works! I use it like this: `gdalsrsinfo -o WKT1 EPSG:28992 > my.prj`
I've marked your reply as the answer.